# Display members of Organic Groups that are members of a given Organic Group in Views

Tags: views, organic-groups

Suppose I have an OG called "Color"
Then, suppose I have OG Groups called:
"Red"
"White"
"Blue"

Within of "Red", there are users that are members.

It is easy to define a filter to display members of "Red".

What I want to do is have a view that displays members of "Red", "White" and "Blue" because each of those OGs are members of "Color".

How do I do that without making each member belong to both "Red", and "Color"?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a relationship to the View for the User entity (current user). From there, you have the ability to create filters based on the OG group(s) that the user belongs to.